# MyWeb.house has hijacked my chrome on mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, malware, blocking, spyware

I have no idea where this come from. Perhaps I installed some apps or some extensions. Recently it keeps pop up in my chrome.

I've googled and found out that there's no answer.

Has anyone have the same experience? Is there any methods to locate and delete this?

(I've experienced the **mackeeper** disaster once and cleaned it up. But this time I even don't know where to find the malware!)